# Ant design get column index

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am building a component using [Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/overview/) with a table that is used like this:

```
                <Table
                    style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
                    components={components}
                    rowClassName={() => 'editable-row'}
                    bordered
                    dataSource={dataSource}
                    columns={columns}
                    pagination={{ hideOnSinglePage: true }}
                    onSelect={(column) => { console.log(column) }}
                    onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
                        return {
                            onClick: event => {
                                var updated = { ...this.state }
                                updated.modals.days.isVisible = true;
                                updated.selectedRowIndex = rowIndex;
                                this.setState(updated)
                            },
                        };
                    }}
                    renderCell={() => {

                    }}
                />
```

When you click on a cell, it should launch a modal (based on what column i have clicked into).
How can I get the column index (or name) when clicking on it? Or other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can render a custom cell by passing an array of [ColumnType](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column) object to `<Table>`.

`ColumnType` have an attribute `render` where you can put your logic (with html) and you will have the value of the record in this column. And as say in the documentation: The return value should be a ReactNode, or an object for colSpan/rowSpan config.

You can adapt the part on the delete popup confirm in the documentation for [Editable Cells](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-edit-cell)

```
const columns: ColumnsType<YourRecord> = [
  {
    key: 'name',
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
  },
  {
    key: 'age',
    title: 'Age',
    dataIndex: 'age',
  },
  {
    key: 'modal',
    title: 'Modal',
    dataIndex: 'modal',
    render: (_: any, record: YourRecord) => {
      return <>html with onClick to open modal</>
    }
  }
];


<Table
                style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}
                components={components}
                rowClassName={() => 'editable-row'}
                bordered
                dataSource={dataSource}
                columns={columns}
                pagination={{ hideOnSinglePage: true }}
                onSelect={(column) => { console.log(column) }}
                onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
                    return {
                        onClick: event => {
                            var updated = { ...this.state }
                            updated.modals.days.isVisible = true;
                            updated.selectedRowIndex = rowIndex;
                            this.setState(updated)
                        },
                    };
                }}
                renderCell={() => {

                }}
            />
```